# Whether an embedding is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a field extension and let $\sigma$ be an embedding from $K$ into $K$ over $F$. If $K/F$ is algebraic, prove that $\sigma \in Aut(K)$.

I know how to prove the case when $K/F$ is finite. But I have no idea how to do it if $K/F$ is not finite.

Answer (score 3):

For $x \in K$ let $R(x) \subseteq K$ denote the set of roots in $K$ of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $F$. Then $\sigma$ maps every element of $R(x)$ into $R(x)$ and as $\sigma$ is injective the restriction of $\sigma$ to $R(x)$ is so too and as $R(x)$ is finite, it is also surjective, thus there exists $y \in R(x)$ such that $\sigma(y) = x$. Hence $\sigma: K \rightarrow K$ is surjective and thus an automorphism.

Comment: I was wondering that if $\sigma \mid _{K}$ is just an isomorphism from $K$ to $K$, is it still an automorphism?

Comment: @Mod.esty An automorphism is an isomorphism with identical target and source, right? So what would be missing here in your opinion?

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry. I means if $\sigma$ over $F$ is just an isomorphism from $F$ to $F$ which dones't need to be the identical map, is $\sigma$ still an automorphism from $K$ to $K$?

Comment: I see now what you mean. To say that $\sigma$ is an embedding from $K$ to $K$ *over* $F$ means that $\sigma|_{F}$ is the identity, so this assumption was already present in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\beta\in K$. we want to show that there exists some $\alpha\in K$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$. Suppose $p(x)=\text{MiPo}_F(\beta)$. Since the set of roots of $p(x)$ in $K$ is finite and for each root $\gamma$, $\sigma(\gamma)$ is also a root, $\sigma$ is a bijection over the roots and we're done !